# Can you use a regex in .babelrc?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Here's what my `.babelrc` looks like. Obviously it doesn't work because of the regex in a JSON file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
  "only": [
    '/client/**/*',
    '/server/**/*',
    /diy-fe-shared/ // <--- regex here breaks
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to use a regex here?

Comment: use the string `'/*/diy-fe-shared/**'` instead?

Comment: Please spellcheck your title.

Comment: Why would you need a regex here? Isn't a simple glob enough?

Comment: @Bergi to be honest I'm not sure. the directory is in node_modules, ie. `node_modules/diy-fe-shared/` and it doesn't seem to work with glob matching but does with regex when I do it in javascript. Maybe something like babel ignores node_modules?

Comment: I'm surprised this question does not have a definitive answer yet. I'm also trying to find out!

Comment: And also trying to the same as you - get babel to transpile my shared components node module!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use regex in `.babelrc` like this: https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx

Create `.babelrc.js`:

```
const plugins = [
  'emotion',
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  plugins.push('transform-react-remove-prop-types');
}

module.exports = {
  plugins,
  presets: [
    ['es2015', {
      loose: true,
      modules: process.env.BABEL_ENV === 'esm' ? false : 'commonjs',
    }],
    'react',
    'stage-2',
  ],
};
```

Then require `.babelrc.js` in `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["./.babelrc.js"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use regular expressions in `.babelrc` files. But you can in `.babelrc.js` files:

Rename your `.babelrc` to `.babelrc.js` and export your configuration object:

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [/* Only run if webpack configures babel-loader's options.envName="production" */]
    }
  },
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
  "only": [
    '/client/**/*',
    '/server/**/*',
    /diy-fe-shared/ // <--- regex here works
  ]
};
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#babelrcjs